# How to segregate the value of a JavaScript objects into Array efficiently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have this following JSON data;

```
data=[
 {
        _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb12",
        title: "Integrated Compute Platform - Operations Lead",
        applylink:
          "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Integrated-Compute-Platform-Operations-Lead/60221",
        jd: "",
        companyname: "JP Morgan Chase Bank",
        location: "Hyderabad/Secunderabad",
        experience: "5-7 yrs",
        salary: "",
        type: "",
        skills: "Cisco",
        startdate: "",
        enddate: "",
        created: "",
        source: "techgig",
        timestamp: 1530363306.1030896,
        __v: 0
      },
      {
        _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb13",
        title: "angular-ui/ux",
        applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/angular-ui-ux/60213",
        jd: "",
        companyname: "Capgemini",
        location: "Pune",
        experience: "6-9 yrs",
        salary: "",
        type: "",
        skills: "UI / UX",
        startdate: "",
        enddate: "",
        created: "",
        source: "techgig",
        timestamp: 1530363306.1030896,
        __v: 0
      },
      {
        _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb14",
        title: "BCM - Big Data CoE Lead",
        applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/BCM-Big-Data-CoE-Lead/60226",
        jd: "",
        companyname: "Capgemini",
        location: "Pune",
        experience: "17-20 yrs",
        salary: "",
        type: "",
        skills: "Big Data",
        startdate: "",
        enddate: "",
        created: "",
        source: "techgig",
        timestamp: 1530363306.1030896,
        __v: 0
      },
      {
        _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb15",
        title: "Staff QA Engineer, Open VisaNet",
        applylink:
          "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Staff-QA-Engineer-Open-VisaNet/60218",
        jd: "",
        companyname: "Visa",
        location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore",
        experience: "7-12 yrs",
        salary: "",
        type: "",
        skills: "Erlang",
        startdate: "",
        enddate: "",
        created: "",
        source: "techgig",
        timestamp: 1530363306.1030896,
        __v: 0
      },
      {
        _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb16",
        title: "Hadoop - Big Data Developer",
        applylink:
          "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Hadoop-Big-Data-Developer/60225",
        jd: "",
        companyname: "Morgan Stanley",
        location: "Mumbai",
        experience: "4-7 yrs",
        salary: "",
        type: "",
        skills: "Big Data",
        startdate: "",
        enddate: "",
        created: "",
        source: "techgig",
        timestamp: 1530363306.1030896,
        __v: 0
      },
      {
        _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb17",
        title: "Specialist UX/UI Designer",
        applylink:
          "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Specialist-UX-UI-Designer/60215",
        jd: "",
        companyname: "Hewlett Packard",
        location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore",
        experience: "5-9 yrs",
        salary: "",
        type: "",
        skills: "UI / UX",
        startdate: "",
        enddate: "",
        created: "",
        source: "techgig",
        timestamp: 1530363306.1030896,
        __v: 0
      },
      {
        _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb18",
        title: "Hadoop - Big Data Developer",
        applylink:
          "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Hadoop-Big-Data-Developer/60225",
        jd: "",
        companyname: "Morgan Stanley",
        location: "Mumbai",
        experience: "4-7 yrs",
        salary: "",
        type: "",
        skills: "Big Data",
        startdate: "",
        enddate: "",
        created: "",
        source: "techgig",
        timestamp: 1530363306.1030896,
        __v: 0
      }]
```

Data is lot more than that, around 1.5 MB coming from a JSON file hosted online, this is just sample, I have to filter the jobs on the basis of location, skill, experience.

What I thought of to add everything to the state then preprocess the data in the 3 diff array with the following format

```
      {
        value: jobData.xxx,
        label: jobData.xxx
      }
```

Push the data in react-select, get from that and use a filter for the whole state and display the result in a nice UI.

The problem here is data is really huge, and no option to get chunks from backend, I have to use the full data at once.

My questions are:-

- How to store the data skill, location and exp segregate in diff array without the duplicated elements, I tried with a map, duplicated element are coming. Iterating through the whole array again to check if it's not there would not be efficient?
- Is there a better way you all propose to do it?

Thanks

Edit-1

So basically what i want 3 json object

```
 var skill = {
        value: jobData.skills,
        label: jobData.skills
      };
      var location = {
        value: jobData.location,
        label: jobData.location
      };
      var experience = {
        value: jobData.experience,
        label: jobData.experience
      };
```

pushed in three array:

```
 var skillList=[];
    var locationList=[];
    var experienceList=[];
```

Which will be inturn set in react state

Edit-2

This is the whole code:

```
import React from "react";
import Style from "./Landing.module.scss";
import JobImage from "./2663543.jpg";
import Select from "react-select";
class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
    //the data mentiond above
    ],
    skills: [],
    location: [],
    experience: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    var skillList=[];
    var locationList=[];
    var experienceList=[];


    this.state.data.map(jobData => {
      var skill = {
        value: jobData.skills,
        label: jobData.skills
      };
      var location = {
        value: jobData.location,
        label: jobData.location
      };
      var experience = {
        value: jobData.experience,
        label: jobData.experience
      };
    });


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className={Style.bigHead}>
          <div className={Style.bigImage}>
            <img src={JobImage} alt="Job Image"></img>
          </div>
          <div className={Style.filters}>
            <Select
              isMulti
              name="location"
              options={this.state.location}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
            />
             <Select
              isMulti
              name="experience"
              options={this.state.experience}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
            />
             <Select
              isMulti
              name="skill"
              options={this.state.skills}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

Comment: You can use `Map`

Comment: You can use `Set`

Comment: Agreed, used map, got the value in the array, but tere is duplites comming, how can i apply filter and reduce

Comment: Yes, i tht of, but set is not supported by react-select where i have to feed the data :-(, i have to again process that set into the react-select

Comment: @AlpitAnand `Map` and `map` are two different things, [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: ok, didnt know that, its `map`

Comment: `value: jobData.xxx, label: jobData.xxx` - what is `xxx`, why have the same thing as value AND label

Comment: React-select takes data in the following format, the xxx refers to skill, experience or location

Comment: A simple solution would be I could loop over every damm time and see if its there, but idk if that would be efficient

Comment: given the `data` Array you've show, can you be more descriptive with what you need as an "output" - e.g., you have 4 distinct skills in those 7 records ... did you want something that has those 4 skills with references to the 7 records they came from, or just a list of 4 skills?

Comment: Ok editing the question

Comment: why it needs to be both the value

Comment: Just skills in an array , since the data is huge I at max want to iterate once

Comment: Ok wait i am posting the whole code, it might give clear picture

Comment: so, in the example you have an array of 7 records in `data` ... would `skillList` array have 7 records - i.e. a one to one relationship?

Comment: No, just the unique skills, edited the question

Comment: I want to segregate all 3 in single map

Comment: so there's no link between the skill and the record it came from ... i.e. in this case, 4 skills - using array map method is not what you want - to do it in a single loop, reduce probably

Comment: Yes exactly, right

Comment: Soo reduce, would give me the list of skills what about the duplicates ?

Comment: Not really, but to get just `skills` you'd do somethng like `let skillsArray = [...new Set(data.map(({skills}) => skills))];` - then you can use that as your value/label - but then you'd repeat that for location and experience - means you iterate `data` 3 times, which you don't want to do ... using reduce, and some clever code, you can build each array in one loop - not sure it would be more performant or not, but you said you wanted to do it in a single loop

Comment: ok , hmmmm, i am trying for set now, really thanks for your time.

Comment: see answer, it may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```
let skillsList = [...new Set(data.map(({skills}) => skills))].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
let locationList = [...new Set(data.map(({location}) => location))].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
let experienceList = [...new Set(data.map(({experience}) => experience))].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
```

```js
let data=[{ _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb12", title: "Integrated Compute Platform - Operations Lead", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Integrated-Compute-Platform-Operations-Lead/60221", jd: "", companyname: "JP Morgan Chase Bank", location: "Hyderabad/Secunderabad", experience: "5-7 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Cisco", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb13", title: "angular-ui/ux", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/angular-ui-ux/60213", jd: "", companyname: "Capgemini", location: "Pune", experience: "6-9 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "UI / UX", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb14", title: "BCM - Big Data CoE Lead", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/BCM-Big-Data-CoE-Lead/60226", jd: "", companyname: "Capgemini", location: "Pune", experience: "17-20 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Big Data", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb15", title: "Staff QA Engineer, Open VisaNet", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Staff-QA-Engineer-Open-VisaNet/60218", jd: "", companyname: "Visa", location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore", experience: "7-12 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Erlang", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb16", title: "Hadoop - Big Data Developer", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Hadoop-Big-Data-Developer/60225", jd: "", companyname: "Morgan Stanley", location: "Mumbai", experience: "4-7 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Big Data", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb17", title: "Specialist UX/UI Designer", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Specialist-UX-UI-Designer/60215", jd: "", companyname: "Hewlett Packard", location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore", experience: "5-9 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "UI / UX", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb18", title: "Hadoop - Big Data Developer", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Hadoop-Big-Data-Developer/60225", jd: "", companyname: "Morgan Stanley", location: "Mumbai", experience: "4-7 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Big Data", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }];

let skillsList = [...new Set(data.map(({skills}) => skills))].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
let locationList = [...new Set(data.map(({location}) => location))].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
let experienceList = [...new Set(data.map(({experience}) => experience))].map(value => ({value, label:value}));

console.log(skillsList);
console.log(locationList);
console.log(locationList);
```

Another way, which may or may not be more performant I don't know, but it iterates data once, not 3 times

```js
let data=[{ _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb12", title: "Integrated Compute Platform - Operations Lead", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Integrated-Compute-Platform-Operations-Lead/60221", jd: "", companyname: "JP Morgan Chase Bank", location: "Hyderabad/Secunderabad", experience: "5-7 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Cisco", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb13", title: "angular-ui/ux", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/angular-ui-ux/60213", jd: "", companyname: "Capgemini", location: "Pune", experience: "6-9 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "UI / UX", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb14", title: "BCM - Big Data CoE Lead", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/BCM-Big-Data-CoE-Lead/60226", jd: "", companyname: "Capgemini", location: "Pune", experience: "17-20 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Big Data", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb15", title: "Staff QA Engineer, Open VisaNet", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Staff-QA-Engineer-Open-VisaNet/60218", jd: "", companyname: "Visa", location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore", experience: "7-12 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Erlang", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb16", title: "Hadoop - Big Data Developer", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Hadoop-Big-Data-Developer/60225", jd: "", companyname: "Morgan Stanley", location: "Mumbai", experience: "4-7 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Big Data", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb17", title: "Specialist UX/UI Designer", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Specialist-UX-UI-Designer/60215", jd: "", companyname: "Hewlett Packard", location: "Bengaluru/Bangalore", experience: "5-9 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "UI / UX", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }, { _id: "5b377db0c97f730014b6eb18", title: "Hadoop - Big Data Developer", applylink: "https://www.techgig.com/jobs/Hadoop-Big-Data-Developer/60225", jd: "", companyname: "Morgan Stanley", location: "Mumbai", experience: "4-7 yrs", salary: "", type: "", skills: "Big Data", startdate: "", enddate: "", created: "", source: "techgig", timestamp: 1530363306.1030896, __v: 0 }];


let {skillsList, locationList, experienceList} = data.reduce((acc, {skills, location, experience}) => {
    acc.skillsList.add(skills);
    acc.locationList.add(location);
    acc.experienceList.add(experience);
    return acc;
}, {skillsList:new Set, locationList:new Set, experienceList:new Set});
skillsList = [...skillsList].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
locationList = [...locationList].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
experienceList = [...experienceList].map(value => ({value, label:value}));
console.log(skillsList);
console.log(locationList);
console.log(experienceList);
```

Comment: So basically, what you are doing here, is getting all 3 by reduce, making 3 new set,and then putting all of it in there, right ?

Comment: Ok cool, really thanks for the help, let me see, if I can optimize it further, with everything in a single map, I have an idea, if I am able to implement, will post the solution

Comment: Nope, wasn't able to, thanks for the solution, you are awesome